# ImageView cannot be cast to com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView

Tags: android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

i am using Smart Image view pragmatically (in java class not in xlm) to get image from URL but it giving an exception that ImageView cannot be cast to com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView 
here is my code.where i am doing wrong?
thanks in advance.

```
   SmartImageView lstimg=(SmartImageView) new ImageView(this);
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams param5 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((width/2)+60, (height/6)-10);
   lstimg.setLayoutParams(param5);
   lstimg.setImageUrl("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wQaH5H2z0qY/UCoZnt5bgnI/AAAAAAAAPE8/uB8rwK5P2rQ/s400/Pakistan-Flag-Facebook-Cover-851x315-100018.jpg");
   img.addView(lstimg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Image view and SmartImage View are different Objects

when you declare it on the xml you do not declare as

- `<ImageView`

and then you do the cast

So for the xml in the case of the Smart Image View you do the following

- `<com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView`

so for using it programatically you do the same stuff as in xml
you must do the following

```
SmartImageView lstimag = new SmartImageView(this);
```

Hope it helps